# Text Overlay relative positioning

Tags: html, css

I changed everything in my code but it still doesnt work. My buttons is on top of the image. i would like my button to be at the buttom of the image and the h1 and content1 to be on top of the image. How can I achieve that so that the buttons will not take up a lot of margins to position the buttons? Thank you

```css
.section{
  margin: 0;
}

#servicebg{
  width: 40rem;
  height: auto;
}

.servicetop{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Floane, san-serif;
    font-size: 3rem; 
    color: #182035;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: -30%;
    z-index: 50;  
}

.content1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: timeless;
  z-index: 5;

}



.row{
  margin-right: 0;

}


.digital{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  width:8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: #182035;
  border-radius: 6rem;
  margin-top: 30rem;
  margin-left: 7.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.digital:hover{
  background-color: #ecb445;
  color: #ecb445;

}

.digitalPin{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  width:8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: #ecb445;
  color: #ecb445;
  border-radius: 6rem;
  margin-top: 30rem;
  margin-left: 7.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.digitalPin:hover{
  background-color: #182035;
  color:#182035;
}

#contentimage{
  width:5rem;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

h2{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}


.formargin{
  margin-top: 2.2rem;
}

.section1{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.section2{
  width:90rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #182035;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.section3{
  width:90rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #182035;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 30rem;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;

}

h3{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  color:#ecb445;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-family: Coldiac;
}

.container{
  background-color:#ecb445;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="section">  
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/servicebg.jpg" id="servicebg" alt="Image Not Found">
      <div class="servicetop">
        <h1> OUR SERVICES </h1>
        <p class="content1">Our services include digital printing, binding, laminating, and cutting. <br>  All the regular
          services you can find in a serious printing shop.   </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="digitalPin"> 
          <img class="d-block" src="images/print.png" id="contentimage" alt="Image Not Found" href="#Digital" onclick ="submitToPage2();">
          <h2 > Digital Printing </h2>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="digital"> 
          <img class="d-block" src="images/binding.png" id="contentimage" alt="Image Not Found" href="#Binding" onclick ="submitToPage2();">
          <h2 class="formargin"> Binding</h2>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="digital"> 
          <img class="d-block" src="images/laminator.png" id="contentimage" alt="Image Not Found" href="#Laminating" onclick ="submitToPage2();">
          <h2 class="formargin"> Laminating</h2>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="digital"> 
          <img class="d-block" src="images/cutting.png" id="contentimage" alt="Image Not Found" href="#Cutting" onclick ="submitToPage2();">
          <h2 class="formargin"> Cutting</h2>
        </div> 
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: What buttons?⠀⠀

Comment: Please edit your code snippit with images that are linked online so it will reproduce your issue.

Comment: Normally you'd use top/left/right/bottom values in relative positions. I don't see you are using any.

Comment: @vanowm its the c;lass with digital and digital pin.. Thanks

Comment: You want them on top, yet you have `margin-top: 30rem;` which pushes them down